# Windows dll files corrupt after removing Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, dll

I recently deleted my Ubuntu partition from my hard drive. I was dual booting. Upon deleting the partition I hibernated Windows to make sure that everything went well. When I started back up again it would not boot and said that GRUB was basically garbage and it couldn’t boot anything.

So I booted to a Ubuntu Live CD and I got "boot-repair" to repair my GRUB and allow me to boot to Windows. When I went back into Windows it wasn’t hibernated anymore, and I didn’t think anything of it. The computer worked fine until I shut it down. I turned it back on and logged in and I thought everything was OK but when I went to run certain programs like Microsoft Word or Photoshop it said that the `.dll` files were corrupt. This also happened to iTunes and other applications.

Now when I try to uninstall Word it says that it cannot be done and when I try a reinstall it just crashes. iTunes installs fine (so it says) but when I try to run it it says that it was not installed correctly. I ended up reinstalling it, several times, with no luck. I really need Microsoft Word and other applications to work! **What can I do?**

Answer (score 0):

I would try, in this order, these steps. If you get errors/messages, stop and post them here so we can better understand the problem

- Run chkdsk on the Windows partition
- Use the "repair" function of the software installers (In Programs and Features, select the software, click "Change" and then select "Repair" when the installer starts)
- Use System Restore
- If you have the Windows installation disk, use the "Reinstall Windows" option in the Recovery control panel under Advanced Recovery Options.

Comment: in that order. i ran disk check. it ran and found a bunch of corrupted files and fixed them, took about 30 mins. change dosnt work on my itunes for some reason. for some reason my system restore has no other restore dates except today... i have no clue why i remember making one not even a few weeks ago. and i do not have a windows installation disk. i do have a acer factory default disk though, but i dont if i want to go that far yet.

Comment: @Megaeverything I hate to say it but you may have to back up the files you can access and reinstall from the recovery disk. It sounds like Windows, possibly the Registry, is corrupted.

Comment: will my acer factory default recovery disk reinstall windows? or does it just have all of the default acer stuff on it? and what is the difference between using "return your computer to factory condition" within windows and my default recovery disks?

Comment: It should completely format the hard disk(s) and reinstall Windows and the default Acer stuff. By "return your computer to factory condition with windows" I assume you mean the 4th option I mentioned. Essentially that requires a Windows disk and does the same thing as the Acer disk EXCEPT it will not have the Acer software installed as well.